# Inconsistent Variable Value in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

**UPDATE:** Simplified the Sample code

I searched for this problem and found it nowhere. I have a function which is a wrapper for `simplecrawler`. Following is the simplified code:

```
const Crawler = require('simplecrawler');

//Initial data is an object with initial.url set to url for crawling     

const startCrawler = function startCrawler() {
      const crawler = new Crawler('http://example.com');
          crawler.start();

    const randomVariable = "set";
  const downloadCondition = crawler.addDownloadCondition((queueItem) => {
      console.log(randomVariable);
  });
};
```

Console:

```
set 
set 
set 
set 
set 
set 
undefined 
set 
set 
undefined 
undefined 
set
```

Problem is that inside the `downloadCondition` the value of the constant `randomVariable` gets undefined for some calls as shown above. The `downloadContition` is called by the crawler instance several times per second. Can there be any explanation for this?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @qxz, its now a minimal complete example. Just requiring simplecrawler which is available as npm package and then using it inside a function is all the wrapper function is doing. I have also included how simply its called from another page

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. crawlStarter(initialData) not crawlStarter(intialData).

Because of the typo, it must be printing undefined for every iteration, you just didn't know that because you didn't print it when it wasn't undefined.

Comment: Thanks Hadas, Its just in the example, I have recreated the above code from the main code. In the orignal files, I have correct name and "initialData" in not undefined in every itereation, its only undefined in certain iterations

Comment: How Patrick? I exported the function if you are talking about that

Comment: Simplified it further